# calculate diameter by using pixel size

Tags: image-processing, pixel, image-segmentation

actually I don't really know how to calculate the diameter of red blood cells by applying image processing techniques? Assume 1 pixel is has a diameter of 100 nm, and 1 RBC has around 3850 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know OpenCV, then you should be able to process the image to identify each individual red blood cells as a contour, or an ellipse, then you can measure the long axis of the contour/ellipse as the red blood cell's diameter in pixels. If you already know the width of 1 pixel represents 100nm, then you can convert the diameter in pixels to diameter in nm.

When you say "1 RBC has around 3850 pixels", does that mean the contour or ellipse has 3850 pixels? Then you still need to measure the "length" of this group of 3850 pixels.

Please show some sample pictures to help people understand and help you.

Answer (score 0):

well..first try find area of a cell  as the number of pixels  contained in the cell. Then use formula Area= pi* diametr^2/4.